# how to query one column by id in sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I was wondering if anyone could help figure this query issue out. I have googled around but I cannot find what I am looking. I hope I can explain it well here.

I have a PRODUCTS table that contains, categoryID, productID, and an imageFile columns.

I am trying to create a function in which I can put into a variable the images that connects to a specific category id.

this is the function I have so far.

```
function get_image_by_category($category_id) {
    global $db;
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM products
              WHERE products.imageFile = :category_id';
    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement->bindValue(":category_id", $category_id);
    $statement->execute();
    $category_image = $statement->fetchAll();
    $statement->closeCursor();
    return $category_image;
}
```

I m using var_dump and it always comes back NULL and array size 0;

This is code where I use a function in my index to get that image.

```
if ($action == 'list_products') {
    $category_id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'category_id', 
            FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
    if ($category_id == NULL || $category_id == FALSE) {
        $category_id = 1;
    }
    $categories = get_categories();
    $category_image = get_image_by_category($category_id);


    var_dump($category_image);
 }
```

PLease let me know if you need any more info.

Thanks!

Comment: If you see that you are matching the category_id with the product image (imageFile). I think you should match $category_id with categoryID in the query

Answer (score 0):

Your query says this:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE products.imageFile = :category_id
```

It doesn't make much sense to compare the image file name to the category id.  This will never come out equal.

Also, you're using `SELECT *`. Pro tip: don't do that in software; instead name the columns you want returned.

Try this query instead:

```
SELECT imagefile FROM products WHERE category_id = :category_id
```

If you have lots of images for each category and you want them all in a single string comma separated, try this.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(imagefile) images FROM products WHERE category_id = :category_id
```

Comment: Yes! I am sorry for the delayed response. I had to change  to ...WHERE categoryID = :category_id, and it worked. Thank you!